# What are the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I am trying to find all the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/4$. I've just proven that the ideals of $R$ × $S$ are precisely the sets of the form $\{(x,y):x \in I,y \in J\}$ for $I\subset R,J \subset S$ ideals.

I can see that I need to find the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4$ but I'm struggling how to do this. I think that a proper ideal can't contain 1 otherwise the ideal is the whole ring. Does this mean that the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is $\{0\}$ and the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/4$ is $\{0,2\}$?

I think this is the case since if 3 was in the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/4$ we would have 3+2=1 meaning that 1 would need to be in the ideal.

Comment: I can recall that for finite products the ideals are of the form $I \times J$, where either $I$ can be $R$ or $J$ can be $S$, one should see this by projection of some ideal to $R$ and $S$. In your example $(1,1) \in I$, $(1,1)(x,y) = (x,y)$ and therefore $I = R \times R$. Edit: I see, you mean that an ideal of $R \times S$ can be a proper subset of $I \times J$, that sounds right...

Comment: Indeed @user028230 my counterexample is not one, abd actually the property I thoughy false is true. My apologies

Comment: @user028230 If $R_1$ and $R_2$ are rings with unity then each ideal $I \subseteq R_1 \times R_2$ is of the form $J_1 \times J_2$. Let $J_i$ be the image of $I$ in the projection to $R_i$. For $(x,y) \in J_1 \times J_2$, there are $(x,y'),(x',y) \in I$; then $(x,y) = (1,0)(x,y')+(0,1)(x',y)$, so $(x,y) \in I$.

Comment: Can you explicitly fix what you mean in your title? It is not clear. I just added the backslashes.

Comment: Rings without unity can act differently. For example let $R = 2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} = \{0,2\}$ where $2^2 = 0$. In $R \times R$, $I = \{(x,y) \mid x=y\} = \{(0,0) , (2,2)\}$ is an ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: there are two ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the zero ideal $(0) = \{0\}$ and the unit ideal $(1) = \{0,1\} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. There are three ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, the zero ideal $(0) = \{0\}$, the ideal $(2) = \{0,2\}$, and the unit ideal $(1) = \{0,1,2,3\} = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

(This is just the same thing that Max said: there are two positive divisors of $2$, $d \mid 2$ for $d=1,2$; and there are three positive divisors of $4$, $d \mid 4$ for $d=1,2,4$.)

So there are $6$ ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, including the zero and unit ideals.

Comment: Hi @Zach, sorry for the slow reply I've been busy with a computing assignment so had to put this to one side for a while! Thanks for clearing this up for me, your answer has really helped. So for it to be a proper ideal, does this mean the unit ideals don't count? Otherwise the ideal is the ring.

Answer (score 9):

Let $\pi : \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ be the canonical projection.

Then by the lattice-isomorphism theorem, all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $\pi(I)$ for $I$ ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $n\mathbb{Z}$.

Those $I$ are precisely the $d\mathbb{Z}$ for $d\mid n$.

Therefore the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are the $d\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $d\mid n$

Comment: For your second line, you can use the more general, and (maybe?) easier "correspondence theorem."

Comment: @AndresMejia : maybe what you call "correspondence theorem" is what I call the lattice-isomorphism theorem. What is the statement you're referring to ?

Comment: Thanks for the help Max, I appreciate you putting it in general for any n.